# How do I cut a stucco wall for a doggie door install?

Tags: stucco, pet-door

I'm in the process of buying a house and I will be installing a dog door because my dog can never decide if he wants to be inside or out lol.

I've done these style before where it goes through the wall but those were always against wood siding on the outside I've never in my life done anything to any house that had stucco so it's an unknown substance to my DIY skills.

Are there any extra precautions or things I need to do when cutting the hole for the door or do I need to get some specific caulk or anything when installing the door?

All the doors going to the yard are sliding glass and I know there are the inserts for them and I've used one in the past but they suck for long term and I've found punching a hole in the walls is the best way to put a dog door in a home that doesn't have a standard wood or metal door going to the yard.

Comment: Is the stucco over a wood framed wall or concrete block?  That makes a big difference in how to cut.

Comment: It's new construction so I'm inclined to think it's over wood but I've not asked the builder specifically if it's wood or block.

Comment: A block wall would be about 8 to 10 inches thick.  How thick is the wall

Answer (score 2):

Cutting a decent hole in stucco isn’t too hard. Since it's essentially rock, the best tool (in my opinion) is an angle grinder with a diamond blade. That blade will go through the metal mesh adequately. Take it slow and wear appropriate PPE. If you want to get a feel for how the stucco cuts, take a smaller square out of the area you actually want to cut as a test.

Some of the pet doors I’ve installed have had really tight tolerances… try to find one that has a good-sized flange overlapping the cut.

Worst case, a little bit of stucco patch will clean up any chipping.

A paintable exterior caulk like dynaflex 230 would work well.

Suggest you open a small hole on the inside first, just to be sure there’s no electrical/plumbing or surprising framing in the way.

One last edit... if you're moved to drill locating holes for the corners from the inside (which makes sense, right, you know exactly where the framing is), then don't do it. This is a 1/4" hole from the inside as viewed from the outside.

[image: stucco mayhem]

Answer (score 0):

I've cut holes in plaster & lath walls for electrical boxes, etc. and I would presume that it's *similar*, though I'd think stucco would be easier on some counts, more difficult on others.

When you're cutting the stucco, the outer surface will likely crumble. Make sure you cut from the outside *first* to ensure a clean cut in the stucco without it crumbling. I would use an oscillating cutter with either a blade specifically designed for stucco (I'm sure they make 'em - they make blades for *every* other specialty purpose) or a fine-tooth metal cutting blade, or, perhaps, a grout cutting blade. Make a nice, neat cut through the outer layer of stucco to ensure you get a clean brake.

Once through the outer layer, you're going to hit the metal lath holding the stucco to the wall. If you're not using a metal blade already, you'll probably want to switch to one now. Cut through the lath, and continue through whatever layers of stucco are between it and the house sheathing (plywood or OSB, possibly solid wood if the house is old).

Once through the stucco, I'd pry the chunk to be removed out of the way, then I'd probably switch to a Sawzall™ type saw to cut through the wood as you would for any other cut.

When installing apply a good bead of caulk (whatever thickness necessary to ensure a good seal) between the door frame and the wall and you should be fine.